# Generate numbers with specific correlation

Tags: r

How to generate a sequence of numbers, which would have a specific correlation (for example 0.56) and would consist of.. say 50 numbers with R program?
Ty.

Comment: You ask for a vector of numbers with a specific correlation. I presume correlation with itself then or did you mean correlation with another set of numbers? Hint: correlation involves 2 vectors of data! If you do mean autocorrelation, do you mean lag 1 correlation = 0.56?

Comment: If you do want two sets with a specified correlation *between* them, `mvrnorm` in the `MASS` package is a good place to start.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Assuming you mean two normal/Gaussian vectors of values with correlation 0.56

We can use `mvrnorm()` from package **MASS**

```
require(MASS)
out <- mvrnorm(50, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1), ncol = 2),
               empirical = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> cor(out)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1.00 0.56
[2,] 0.56 1.00
```

The `empirical = TRUE` bit is important otherwise the actual correlation achieved is subject to randomness too and will not be exactly the stated value with larger discrepancies for smaller samples.

### Assuming you mean a lag 1 correlation of 0.56 & Gaussian random variables

For this one you can use the `arima.sim()` function:

```
> arima.sim(list(ar = 0.56), n = 50)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 50 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  0.62125233 -0.04742303  0.57468608 -0.07201988 -1.91416757 -1.11827563
 [7]  0.15718249  0.63217365 -1.24635896 -0.22950855 -0.79918784  0.31892842
[13]  0.33335688 -1.24328177 -0.79056890  1.08443057  0.55553819  0.33460674
[19] -0.33037659 -0.65244221  0.70461755  0.61450122  0.53731454  0.19563672
[25]  1.73945110  1.27119241  0.82484460  1.58382861  1.81619212 -0.94462052
[31] -1.36024898 -0.30964390 -0.94963216 -3.75725819 -1.77342095 -1.20963799
[37] -1.76325350 -1.20556172 -0.94684678 -0.85407649  0.14922226 -0.31109945
[43]  0.39456259  0.89610859 -0.70913792 -2.27954408 -1.14722464  0.39140446
[49]  0.66376227  1.63275483
```

Comment: Do you how to the the same but for a log-normal distribution with a no-semidefinite matrix?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to specify those matrices, other options are `corgen` from `ecodist`:

```
library("ecodist")
xy <- corgen(len = 50, r = 0.56, epsilon = 0.01)
```

Or rolling your own:

```
simcor <- function (n, xmean, xsd, ymean, ysd, correlation) {
    x <- rnorm(n)
    y <- rnorm(n)
    z <- correlation * scale(x)[,1] + sqrt(1 - correlation^2) * 
             scale(resid(lm(y ~ x)))[,1]
    xresult <- xmean + xsd * scale(x)[,1]
    yresult <- ymean + ysd * z
    data.frame(x=xresult,y=yresult)
}
```

Test

```
> r <- simcor(n = 50, xmean = 12, ymean = 30, xsd = 3, ysd = 4, correlation = 0.56)
> cor(r$x,r$y)
[1] 0.56
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `rmvnorm` from the `mvtnorm` package to sample from the multivariate normal distribution. For example for correlation of 0.56:

```
library("mvtnorm")
foo <- rmvnorm(10000,c(0,0),matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1),2,2))
```

Test:

```
> cor(foo[,1],foo[,2])
[1] 0.5611207
```