# R: Create dataset with specific correlation in r

Tags: r, random, dataset, correlation

How can i create a dataset with two columns having a specific correlation to each other? I want to be able to define the number of values which will be created and specify the correlation the output should have.

The question is similar to this one: [Generate numbers with specific correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291308/generate-numbers-with-specific-correlation)

One of the answers was to use:

```
out <- mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1),, ncol = 2), 
                mpirical = TRUE)
```

Producing an output like this:

```
            [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] -0.4152618  0.033311146
 [2,]  0.7617759 -0.181852441
 [3,] -1.6393045 -1.054752469
 [4,] -1.7872420 -0.605214425
 [5,]  0.9581152  2.511000955
 [6,]  0.5048160 -0.278329145
 [7,]  0.8656220  0.483521747
 [8,] -0.1385699  0.017395548
 [9,]  0.3261103 -0.932889606
[10,]  0.5639388  0.007808691
```

with the following correlation table cor(out):

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1.00 0.56
[2,] 0.56 1.00
```

But i want the data set to **contain higher, no negative and more far away numbers** for example:

```
       x   y
   1   5   5
   2  20  20
   3  30  30
   4 100 100
```

having a correlation of 1:

```
    x y
  x 1 1
  y 1 1
```

With more far away i mean "more" random and bigger in their value like in my sample above.

Is there are (easy) way to archive something like that?

Comment: "A key mathematical property of the Pearson correlation coefficient is that it is invariant to separate changes in location and scale in the two variables." => why don't you just scale `out` to put it in the desired range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correlation isn't affecting by linear transformation of the underlying variables.  So the most direct way to get what you want could be:

```
out <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0,0), 
                     Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1),, ncol = 2), 
                     empirical = TRUE))

out$V1.s <- (out$V1 - min(out$V1))*1000+10
out$V2.s <- (out$V2 - min(out$V2))*200+30
```

Now the data frame `out` has "shifted" columns `V1.s` and `V2.s` which are non-negative and "large".  You can use whatever numbers you want instead of 1000, 10, 200, and 30 in my code above.  The answer for the correlation will still be 0.56.

```
> cor(out$V1.s, out$V2.s)
[1] 0.56
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as imaged!
Do you perhaps know how i could archive something like that, but instead having just whole numbers (positive integer)?

Comment: Deset, if my answer was helpful please consider accepting or at least upvoting it.  To make the numbers integers, I don't know of an exact method, but you could approximate the desired correlation coefficient by simply transforming to a large range and then rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: note that rounding will slightly increase your variance (e.g.  `var(floor(rnorm(1000000)))` is approximately 1.08 whereas `var(rnorm(1000000))` is approximately 1.   You may find [this link](http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/) helpful

Comment: Thanks again rounding solved that issue. I thought it would change the correlation, but it seems with the number of values i need the change in the correlation is not crucial enough to make a difference.
Jthorpe thanks for the notice and the link!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Curt F. This was a help to me in generating some simulation data sets. I added some options to specify the approx. mean and range desired for X and Y. It also provides output so that you can check the slope and intercept as well as plotting the points and regression line.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
# Desired correlation
d.cor <- 0.5
# Desired mean of X
d.mx <- 8
# Desired range of X
d.rangex <- 4
# Desired mean of Y
d.my <- 5
# Desired range of Y
d.rangey <- 2
# Calculations to create multipliation and addition factors for mean and range of X and Y
mx.factor <- d.rangex/6
addx.factor <- d.mx - (mx.factor*3)
my.factor <- d.rangey/6
addy.factor <- d.my - (my.factor*3)
# Generate data
out <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(1000, mu = c(0,0), 
                             Sigma = matrix(c(1,d.cor,d.cor,1), ncol = 2), 
                             empirical = TRUE))
# Adjust so that values are positive and include factors to match desired means and ranges
out$V1.s <- (out$V1 - min(out$V1))*mx.factor + addx.factor
out$V2.s <- (out$V2 - min(out$V2))*my.factor + addy.factor
# Create liniear model to calculate intercept and slope
fit <- lm(out$V2.s ~ out$V1.s, data=out)
coef(fit)
# Plot scatterplot along with regression line
ggplot(out, aes(x=V1.s, y=V2.s)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed() + geom_smooth(method='lm')
# Produce summary table
summary(out)
```