# How to simulate a vector that is correlated (in a different way) to two other existing vectors

Tags: r, simulate

I would like to simulate one vector that is correlated with two other existing variables. What I tried so far

```
# some correlation matrix
desiredCorrelations = matrix(c(1, .4, 0, 
                              .4, 1, .3,
                               0, .3, 1), nrow = 3)

# some simulated data based on the correlation matrix
dat = mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = rep(3, 3), Sigma = desiredCorrelations, empirical = TRUE) 

n = nrow(dat)
k = ncol(desiredCorrelations)
x = matrix( rnorm(n*k), nc=k )
x[,1] = dat[,1]
y = x %*% solve(chol(var(x))) %*% chol(desiredCorrelations)
# cor(y)      # Desired correlation matrix

apply(dat, 2, summary)
apply(y, 2, summary)
```

Based on this piece of code, the correlations are correct, but only the first column of y is identical to the first column of the originally simulated data. However, I would like two columns to stay the same, while the third column is simulated with the the desired correlation matrix taken into account.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or tips!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a function for this based on [MattBagg's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291308/generate-numbers-with-specific-correlation) that takes a vector x and returns a vector with the specified mean, sd, and correlation:

```
simcor <- function (x, ymean=0, ysd=1, correlation=0) {
    n <- length(x)

    y <- rnorm(n)
    z <- correlation * scale(x)[,1] + sqrt(1 - correlation^2) * 
         scale(resid(lm(y ~ x)))[,1]
    yresult <- ymean + ysd * z
    yresult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the faux package: https://debruine.github.io/faux/

First create the two variables you want the third to be correlated with (rnorm_pre() will require at least 4-ish such pairs of variables, so I generate 4 sets rather than just one, below):

```
> sx1x2 <- rnorm_multi(n=4, vars=2,mu=0,sd=1,r=.1)
> sx1x2
            X1          X2
1  0.295255640 -0.28770654
2 -0.326833060  1.10811640
3  0.008780557  0.04629117
4 -1.658893622 -1.56070681
>
```

Next, create the third variable so that it is correlated by 0.5 with the first and 0.3 with the second:

```
> y1<-rnorm_pre(sx1x2, r = c(0.5, 0.3))
> y1
[1]  1.5205031  0.4098795 -1.1482235 -1.4352354
>
```

Obviously with only 4 samples, the measured correlations will be off:

```
> cov(sx1x2[,1],y1)
[1] 0.8037426
> cov(sx1x2[,2],y1)
[1] 0.6967516
```

But with a larger sample, you can see the generate data is correct:

```
> sx1x2 <- rnorm_multi(n=1000, vars=2,mu=0,sd=1,r=.1)
> y1<-rnorm_pre(sx1x2, r = c(0.5, 0.3))
> c(cov(sx1x2[,1],y1),cov(sx1x2[,2],y1))
[1] 0.5278817 0.3277606
>
```

Hope that helps!