# Generate numbers with specific correlation [with only positive values in the output]

Tags: r, function, correlation

I want to obtain a dataframe with simulated values which have a specific correlation to each other.

I need to use this function, but in the returned output there are also negative values, which do not have meaning for my purposes:

```
COR  <- function (n, xmean, xsd, ymean, ysd, correlation) {
    x <- rnorm(n)
    y <- rnorm(n)
    z <- correlation * scale(x)[,1] + sqrt(1 - correlation^2) * 
             scale(resid(lm(y ~ x)))[,1]
    xresult <- xmean + xsd * scale(x)[,1]
    yresult <- ymean + ysd * z
    data.frame(x=xresult,y=yresult)
}
```

Please note that my question starts from this previous post (currently closed):
[another similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291308/generate-numbers-with-specific-correlation)

Is there a method able to exclude from the final output all the rows which have at least one negative value? (in another terms, x and y must be always positives). 
I spent many hours without any concrete result.....

Comment: *"but in the returned output there are also negative values"* well yes, obviously, because you're sampling `x` and `y` from a normal distribution. Why not sample from a continuous distribution with a strictly positive support? Like a Gamma, log-normal, etc.?

Comment: In the truth, even if I sample only from strictly positive values (e.g. from the right part of a normal distribution with mean = 0) I obtain x or y negative values in the final output. I would like to apply a posteriori control in the code in order to preserve only positive rows in the final output.

Comment: So do you want to draw samples from two arbitrary distributions that have a fixed correlation, or do you want to draw samples from two normal distributions with a fixed mean, sd, *and* a fixed correlation?

Comment: [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/generate-a-random-variable-with-a-defined-correlation-to-an-existing-variables) seems highly relevant.

Comment: I would like to obtain the second option you mentioned: 'x' and 'y'  with two normal distributions with a fixed mean, sd, and a fixed correlation. I am studying the post you kindly reported to my attention, but at the present it is too complicated for my skills.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering rows which have at least one negative value can be done with the `apply` function, e.g.

```
df <- simcor(100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.8)
filter <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x < 0) > 0)
df <- df[!filter,]
plot(df)
```

First, I create a dataframe `df` from your funcion. Then, I apply the function `sum(x < 0) > 0` rowwise to the dataframe (the second argument of apply, `1` indicates to go along the first dimension of the dataframe or array). This will create a logical vector that is `TRUE` for every row with at least one negative value. Subsetting the dataframe with the inverse of that (`!filter`) leaves you with all rows that have no negative values.

**UPDATE**:

Seems like the package `VineCopula` offers functions to create distributions with a given correlation. However, I did not dive into the math as deep so I was not able to fully grasp how copulas (i.e. multivariate probability distributions) work. Using this package, you can at least create e.g. two gaussian distributions.

```
library(VineCopula)
BC <- BiCop(family = 1, par = 0.9)
sim <- BiCopSim(N = 1000, obj = BC)
cor(sim[,1], sim[,2])
plot(sim)
```

You might be able to then scale the resulting matrix to achieve a certain standard derivation.

Comment: Since (Pearson's) correlation coefficient depends on the number of observations, removing samples will change the correlation. So this method will *not* conserve a fixed correlation. Try it out.

Comment: Thank you, but @MauritsEvers is fully right in his observation above, so the code you posted cannot work

Comment: If, like you mentioned in you initial question, you absolutely _need_ to use the given function, you will always have the possibility of negative values and any changes to the data afterwards (like excluding values) will potentially change the correlation like @MauritsEvers pointed out. However, I do not see a way around this with the information given. Can you be more specific on your task?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I want to produce a given length ('n') of two series of positive numbers ('x' and 'y') satisfying an a priori specified mean and standard deviation for the variables, and a given correlation between them. The use of the code I posted above is not mandatory, but I started to work on that script. What is important is the final result, and to obtain it through a reproducible code in R.